How to block access to a WiFi BSSID?
With a typical Linux distribution there are tools like wpa_cli, which can block specific BSSIDs, so that I can avoid connecting to certain bad access points that share the same SSID with good ones.  How can I do the same on a rooted Android phone?

Possible related: How can I connect to a specific access point in a group having the same SSID?
